# How can I attach a line item field to a custom checkout pane?

Tags: entities, commerce

How can I attach a line item field (as form element) to a custom checkout pane ?

I tried the following with `commerce_line_item_save($line_item);`

```
function MODULE_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {  
  //...
  //1st TRY, which in my opinion should be the right API fn ?
  global $language;
  field_attach_form('commerce_order', $order, $pane_form, $form_state, $language->language, array('field_name' => 'field_paxsup'));
```

Which returns

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in field.attach.inc on line
>   208.

field.attach.inc on line 208  `$items = isset($entity->{$field_name}[$langcode]) ? $entity->{$field_name}[$langcode] : array();`

Precision: the custom checkout pane is working great with a basic field as below

```
$pane_form['nickname'] = array(
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 //and so on...
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer just after posting : so the correct one is

`field_attach_form($entity_type, $entity, &$form, &$form_state, $langcode = NULL, $options = array())`

**First parameter**

`entity_type` is the entity type you want to attach, not the one you want to attach *to* (see why non native english speakers have problems sometimes... Duh !).

**Second parameter**

`entity` expects an object , not a string ! Don't do

`field_attach_form('commerce_line_item', 'my_line_item_type' ...`

but :

```
$line_item = new stdClass();
$line_item->type = 'line_item_liberte'; 

field_attach_form('commerce_line_item', $line_item, $pane_form, $form_state, $langcode, array('field_name' => 'field_paxsup'));
```

In checkout pane context, load the line item

```
function MODULE_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) { 

  $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($order->commerce_line_items['und'][0]['line_item_id']);
  field_attach_form('commerce_line_item', $line_item, $pane_form, $form_state, $langcode, array('field_name' => 'field_paxsup'));
  //...
```